# React onmouseenter/onmouseleave not changing state on mouse leave with immer produce function

Tags: reactjs, mouseevent, setstate, immer.js

In this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-spence-g7eyxo) I am trying to change the background color of a div element on mouseenter and revert it on mouse leave. It only works on the outermost edge divs.

I know that setting state is "async" but the fact it does work on the outer edge makes me question it being a closure issue.

Using onMouseOut does not make a difference. I could be approaching a problem like this the wrong way completely but I cannot figure out what is wrong with the current implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the state bases on previous value. That's a closure issue. You don't need to use the `editGrid` state. Instead use setEditGrid with produce function which will pass previous value as first argument.

```
setEditGrid(
  produce((draft) => {
    draft[rowIndex][colIndex] = 2;
  })
);
```

You can just update changes in that argument (Mostly we call it as draft).
You can read more passing a function in setState in [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

You can improve one thing in your code. You don't need to set `id` to each grid block. Instead use the `rowIndex` and `colIndex` if there's no such requirement that affects the grid structure.

```
import { useState, Fragment } from "react";
import produce from "immer";
const colors = ["", "#A5668B", "#FACFAD", "#F8BD7F", "#7DAF9C", "#95190C"];

export default function App() {
  const [editGrid, setEditGrid] = useState([
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  ]);

  // const [currentShip, setCurrentShip] = useState(2);

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <div style={{ display: "grid", textAlign: "center", gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(11, minmax(10px, 50px))" }}>
        {["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"].map((letter) => {
          return (
            <div key={letter} className='p-4'>
              {letter}
            </div>
          );
        })}
        {editGrid.map((rows, rowIndex) =>
          rows.map((col, colIndex) => {
            return (
              <Fragment key={`${rowIndex}-${colIndex}`}>
                {colIndex === 0 && <div>{rowIndex + 1}</div>}
                <div
                  style={{ backgroundColor: colors[editGrid[rowIndex][colIndex]], aspectRatio: 1 / 1 }}
                  onMouseOver={(e) => {
                    setEditGrid(
                      produce((draft) => {
                        draft[rowIndex][colIndex] = 2;
                      })
                    );
                  }}
                  onMouseOut={(e) => {
                    setEditGrid(
                      produce((draft) => {
                        draft[rowIndex][colIndex] = 0;
                      })
                    );
                  }}
                >
                  {editGrid[rowIndex][colIndex]}
                </div>
              </Fragment>
            );
          })
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```